# How to use AdMod with Mono for Android?

Tags: admob, xamarin.android

Do you have experience using Mono for Android and AdMob?
Can you describe how you accomplish it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James here created a nice binding project here based on Greg Shackles v4 bindings:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroid-Admob6

Comment: This was perfect, got it integrated in 2 minutes! Thank you for the link.